# Updating date field in database inserts all zero values

Tags: php, mysql

When code updates date field in database, the date becomes 0000/00/00. But when I print the date variable in web page with `echo`, output prints correct date. Any ideas how could update work.

Code:

```
$query=date('y/m/d');
$date="UPDATE student SET datum_upisa=$query WHERE _broj_indeksa='$broj_indeksa'";
mysqli_query($con,$date);
```

Comment: Try datum_upisa = '$query' in your query.

Comment: Is `$broj_indeksa` escaped before this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use quote for `date`, change this line

```
$date="UPDATE student SET datum_upisa='$query' WHERE _broj_indeksa='$broj_indeksa'";
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `'$query'` instead of `$query`

```
$date="UPDATE student SET datum_upisa='$query' WHERE _broj_indeksa='$broj_indeksa'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date="UPDATE student SET datum_upisa='$query' 
       WHERE _broj_indeksa='$broj_indeksa'";
```

When you use $query instead of '$query' , MySql is not able to parse a literal string $query to 
date type and silently converts to a zero value.